# In publish meta-box, how to make post_status conditional to certain users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I want to let custom user role 'cm' only see 'cm approved' and 'cm rejected', and'rm' only see 'cm approved', 'rm approved', 'rm rejected' in the publish meta-box.
See my screenshot below, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution after I talked to a wordpress expert in the meetup. As I am using the Edit Flow, everything becomes easy. I recommend you install that tool too.

```
add_filter('ef_custom_status_list', 'custom_by_roles');
function custom_by_roles($custom_statuses){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $permitted_statuses = array();
    if ($current_user -> roles[0] == 'cm'){ 
        $permitted_statuses = array(
            'cm-approved',
            'cm-rejected',
            'received'
        );
    }elseif ($current_user -> roles[0] == 'rm'){
        $permitted_statuses = array(
            'cm-approved',
            'rm-approved',
            'rm-rejected'
        );
    }
    foreach($custom_statuses as $key => $custom_status){
        if(!in_array($custom_status->slug, $permitted_statuses))
        unset($custom_statuses[$key]);
    }
    return $custom_statuses;
}
```